# Gstreamer 1.0 - Creating custom message/event/signal

Tags: gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0

I am writing a custom plugin for gstreamer 1.0 in C.
This plugin perform some processing on frames and should send an event to the application whenever some conditions are met.
It should not block the pipeline not interfere with it, just a signal so the application can trigger an action unrelated to the pipeline on the side.

The processing is working well but ... i don't know what to do next.
There is a lot of already existing message like EOS or seek but how do i create my own?
The message should contain custom data and therefore i must create one myself that i could send.

Either by sending events or signal i could not find any examples/documentations/explainations on how to handle custom events from a plugin.

I don't even have a sample code to start with.

Any insight would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at the `fpsdisplaysink` element:

https://github.com/GStreamer/gst-plugins-bad/blob/master/gst/debugutils/fpsdisplaysink.c

This one emits signals which the application can connect to. Most interesting probably the signal creation:

```
g_signal_new ("fps-measurements", G_TYPE_FROM_CLASS (klass),
      G_SIGNAL_RUN_LAST, 0, NULL, NULL, NULL,
      G_TYPE_NONE, 3, G_TYPE_DOUBLE, G_TYPE_DOUBLE, G_TYPE_DOUBLE);
```

and the periodically triggering of said signal:

```
g_signal_emit (G_OBJECT (self),
        fpsdisplaysink_signals[SIGNAL_FPS_MEASUREMENTS], 0, rr, dr,
        average_fps);
```

Detailed information should be found at the GLib signals documentation:

https://developer.gnome.org/gobject/stable/gobject-Signals.html

### #

Alternatively you create your own `GstMessage` and post it on the bus. See the GstMessage documentation:

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstMessage.html

```
GstMessage *gst_message_new_application (GstObject *src,
    GstStructure *structure);
```

You can then wrap your data inside the `GstStructure`. And then post the message to the bus with `gst_bus_post()`.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. I went to creating my own GstMessage with its own GstStructure and gst_bus_post.  It works but i don't actuelly know how to get a callback from the application itself everytime it is triggered. Is gst_bus_add_watch the proper way ?

Comment: I also looked into gst_bus_pop_filtered but it should be in somekind of a runLoop for my event and stop the program if a receive an error or an EOS event. Is there an example somewhere with a runLoop catching application events? My main application is in python, i found https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/bus.html but i don't really know how i could translate this in python.

Comment: There are generally three ways. 1) You have a GMainLoop that runs and you can add a bus watch via gst_bus_add_watch(). 2) You poll the bus in your application via gst_bus_poll() periodically. 3) You set a synchronous handler via gst_bus_set_sync_handler(). Whatever way you go with - you should definitely have it as all error/eos/etc reporting while the pipeline is running ends up there. And sorry, I don't speak python.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you Florian for your insight which helped me a lot.
I ended up using gst_message_new and gst_post_bus.

For those who might be interested here is the code in python where i implemented a run loop.

```
def connect(bus, name):
    def _connect(f):
        bus.connect(name, f)
        return f
    return _connect

....
    bus = self.pipeline.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()

    ret = self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.PLAYING)
    if ret == Gst.StateChangeReturn.FAILURE:
        logger.error("ERROR: Unable to set the pipeline to the playing state")

    loop = GObject.MainLoop()

    print()

    @connect(bus, "message::"+Gst.MessageType.get_name(Gst.MessageType.ERROR))
    def on_error(bus, message):
        err, dbg = message.parse_error()
        print("ERROR:", message.src.get_name().encode('utf-8'), ":", err.message.encode('utf-8'))
        if dbg:
            print("debugging info:", dbg)

        loop.quit()

    @connect(bus, "message::"+Gst.MessageType.get_name(Gst.MessageType.EOS))
    def on_eos(bus, message):
        logger.info("End-Of-Stream reached")
        loop.quit()

    .... other events

    try:
        loop.run()
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        pass

    print("START : Pipeline has stopped")
    self.pipeline.set_state(Gst.State.NULL)
```